# Camera2 video recording

Tags: android, android-camera

I've implemented [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2basic/Camera2BasicFragment.java) offical Google `Camera2` example with minor changes into my app to take pictures in a custom camera. I need to also provide the option for video recording, but I can't find an example- maybe because the `Camera2` API is relatively new.

Does anyone have examples/tutorials on how to either A) modify the above code to also allow video recording, or B) implement video recording in a new fragment, while using the `Camera2` API?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

google camera2video sample code :
    https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video

Comment: Its currently buggy and crashes, but I have submitted a PR https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/pull/6 based on work from someone on the Xamarin port.

Comment: @MadhavaJay Any insight on why closing and reopening is better than stop and reset?

Comment: Im not sure, sorry I havent looked recently, but that was the only way I could get the code to work, its possible its been updated since, but its a bit disappointing that Googles Sample Code isnt continually updated to run on their latest platforms.